# Load URL by .png from a webview

Tags: android, url, webview

After I've filtered out the extension inside my webview, ".png". How can I then use the entire link to open a new activity?

```
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if(url.contains(".png")) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "png clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Instead of having my toast, I want to load the URL that was clicked. I'm new to programming in general so I'm not sure the approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would really like to know the use case, but assuming that what you want is just to load that PNG in the webview, you could do this:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if(url.contains(".png")) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Kind regards

Comment: Thank you, giving this a try now.  I'm making myself a simple android tutorial app for self reference.   My app's webview loads the png file into a new view, but I lose the tutorial behind the png that loaded. Since the android back button has the applications activity stack to back I don't have navigation like chromes back button.

Comment: Thank you Dario! This is looking great :)

Now I just need to see how to add back button navigation cleanly into the webview :)

Comment: Awesome bro! happy to help anytime :)